# Removing elements from a list that is used by liveData does not remove any

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

```
Android 4.1.2
Kotlin 1.4.21
```

I have the following live data that I add to, but when it comes to removing it doesn't remove any elements.

```
val selectedLiveData by lazy { MutableLiveData<List<Core>>() }
```

I don't want to trigger the observers so I am not assigning the `value` as I just want to remove a single element from the liveData list and only trigger when adding.

None of the following work

```
selectedLiveData.value?.toMutableList()?.apply {
    removeAt(0)
}

selectedLiveData.value?.toMutableList()?.apply {
    removeFirst()
}
                
selectedLiveData.value?.toMutableList()?.apply {
     remove(Core)
}
```

I am adding my elements like this and then assigning the value so the observers to this live data get updated:

```
selectedLiveData.value = selectedLiveData.value?.toMutableList()?.apply {
      add(core)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you wanted is

```
val selectedLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Core>>(emptyList())
```

Then

```
selectedLiveData.value = selectedLiveData.value.toMutableList().apply {
    removeAt(0)
}.toList()
```

Answer (score 3):

So what are you doing exactly:
You create a `MutableLiveData` with a `List` of objects. As we know in Kotlin `List` is immutable, so it's `readonly`.
If you want to add / remove items from a list, you should use `MutableList`.

If we look the documentation of `toMutableList` which you are using:

```
 /**
 * Returns a new [MutableList] filled with all elements of this collection.
 */
public fun <T> Collection<T>.toMutableList(): MutableList<T> {
    return ArrayList(this)
}
```

So every time you try to remove an item via:

```
selectedLiveData.value?.toMutableList()
```

you actually perform that operation on a new `MutableList` not the original one.

If you want to add / remove I suggest you to use `MutableList` in your `MutableLiveData` so you can create something similar to this:

```
    private val selectedLiveData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Int>>()

    // Init
    selectedLiveData.value = mutableListOf(100, 200)
    
    // Add items
    selectedLiveData.value?.add(2)
    selectedLiveData.value?.add(10)
    selectedLiveData.value?.add(50)

    // Remove item
    selectedLiveData.value?.remove(2)
```

Comment: For this I cannot change to `MutableList` as the code is already written with a `List`. That is why I was using `toMutableList()` Is there anyway to do this with a list?

Comment: Not really, in Kotlin `List` is immutable so it has only read only access. If you want to add/remove you will have to use `MutableList`.

Comment: Thanks, but how come I can add items using the following: `selectedLiveData.value?.toMutableList()?.apply { add(core) }`

Comment: Because `toMutableList ` create new `MutableList` which supports adding/removing items. You are not performing those action on your main `List`. You can keep a reference to that `MutableList` returned by `toMutableList `, but it's not the best way to achieve what you need.

Comment: Stop giving people advice to make MutableList inside MutableLiveData, it is bad practice.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you explain why it is a bad practice?

Comment: Because mutating the dataset of an observable source in place is bad as it will not notify observers of changes https://observablehq.com/@tmcw/observable-anti-patterns-and-code-smells#mutation

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that is true if the dataset is modified i.e. add, remove, or an element updated. The observers will not be called. Only if the `LiveData.value` set to the updated value. Not sure why that would be considered bad practice.

Comment: Not notifying the observers on data change is anti-thetical to what LiveData was made for and is completely unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedLiveData.postValue(selectedLiveData.value.toMutableList().apply {
    removeAt(0)
}.toList())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.